# When app is killed I am not able to route to a specific page with notification in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am trying to go to a page when notification is clicked. It works fine when app is in background or foreground but it is not working when app is killed.

When app is killed it opens the app but doesn't go to the route defined in the notification data.

Need a quick solution

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message)=>
    NotificationPop().onOpenApp(message, navigatorKey));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to navigate or catch data from your notification(also known as RemoteMessage) when the app is killed, you need to use the following function of Firebase Package:

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if(message != null && message.data['title'] == 'SomeTitle') {
        //Navigate to a page
      }
    });
```

Place the above function in the init function of your desired page and whenever your app navigates to that page, the above function will get called.
I am assuming you have integrated the firebase in your app correctly.

Comment: You mean when I am navigated to my home screen then I have to call this function right?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Absolutely yes. I assume your app automatically routes a logged in user to their homepage, so in the homepages onInit you can add this.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase package provides different methods to handle different scenarios, i.e. Terminated app, app in background and open app.

You have to implement `getInitialMessage()` method to handle notification in terminated app.

```
 FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) {
   //YourCode  
  });
```

You can also check other methods to manage diff scenarios like duplicate notifications:

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) //YourCode  });
```

Comment: I have added this method but nothing happening

Comment: You have to check firebase configuration for your project. Make sure you have initialise firebase instance in main() of your project .   await Firebase.initializeApp();

Comment: Yes I have initialized it there

Comment: Try to add log in getInitialMessage() method. keep your device connected with android studio and check if you are able to get logs. Try to debug.

Comment: Nope when app is killed I am not able to get any logs

Comment: are you Mac(iOS) user?

Comment: no I am using windows

Comment: Np, I would like to request you to check once all configuration steps especially for background and killed app. https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging. Maybe there is some permission or step of configuration missed out.

Comment: Ok sure I will check it too